# Remove child tags but keep the text in xml?

Tags: python, regex, xml

I have a xml which looks like this

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf8'?>
<all>
<articletitle>text1<x> </x></articletitle>
<affiliation><x> </x><label id="aff1">12</label><affnorg>College of Materials Science and Engineering</affnorg><x>, </x><affnorg>Guangdong Research Center for Interfacial Engineering of Functional Materials</affnorg><x>, </x><affnorg>Shenzhen University</affnorg><x>, </x><affnadd>3688 Nanhai Ave</affnadd><x>, </x><affncity>Shenzhen</affncity><x>, </x><affnpost>518060</affnpost><x>, </x><affncountry>PR China</affncountry><x>.</x></affiliation>
<affiliation><x> </x><label id="aff2">2</label><affnorg>Key Laboratory of Optoelectronic Devices and Systems of Ministry of Education and Guangdong Province</affnorg><x>, </x><affnorg>College of Optoelectronic Engineering</affnorg><x>, </x><affnorg>Shenzhen University</affnorg><x>, </x><affnadd>3688 Nanhai Ave</affnadd><x>, </x><affncity>Shenzhen</affncity><x>, </x><affnpost>518060</affnpost><x>, </x><affncountry>PR China</affncountry><x>.</x></affiliation>
</all>
```

The task is that I have to remove all the `<x>` tags and preserve their text only in `affiliation` tag, Using ElementTree I can remove the tag but it will remove the text as well but I want that text to be in parent tag, SO that my new xml looks like this

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf8'?>
<all>
<articletitle>text1<x> </x></articletitle>
<affiliation> <label id="aff1">12</label><affnorg>College of Materials Science and Engineering</affnorg>, <affnorg>Guangdong Research Center for Interfacial Engineering of Functional Materials</affnorg>, <affnorg>Shenzhen University</affnorg>, <affnadd>3688 Nanhai Ave</affnadd>, <affncity>Shenzhen</affncity>, <affnpost>518060</affnpost>, <affncountry>PR China</affncountry>.</affiliation>
<affiliation> <label id="aff2">2</label><affnorg>Key Laboratory of Optoelectronic Devices and Systems of Ministry of Education and Guangdong Province</affnorg>, <affnorg>College of Optoelectronic Engineering</affnorg>, <affnorg>Shenzhen University</affnorg>, <affnadd>3688 Nanhai Ave</affnadd>, <affncity>Shenzhen</affncity>, <affnpost>518060</affnpost>, <affncountry>PR China</affncountry>.</affiliation>
</all>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `BeautifulSoup` you can use `unwrap()` function:

```
data = '''<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf8'?>
<all>
<articletitle>text1<x> </x></articletitle>
<affiliation><x> </x><label id="aff1">12</label><affnorg>College of Materials Science and Engineering</affnorg><x>, </x><affnorg>Guangdong Research Center for Interfacial Engineering of Functional Materials</affnorg><x>, </x><affnorg>Shenzhen University</affnorg><x>, </x><affnadd>3688 Nanhai Ave</affnadd><x>, </x><affncity>Shenzhen</affncity><x>, </x><affnpost>518060</affnpost><x>, </x><affncountry>PR China</affncountry><x>.</x></affiliation>
<affiliation><x> </x><label id="aff2">2</label><affnorg>Key Laboratory of Optoelectronic Devices and Systems of Ministry of Education and Guangdong Province</affnorg><x>, </x><affnorg>College of Optoelectronic Engineering</affnorg><x>, </x><affnorg>Shenzhen University</affnorg><x>, </x><affnadd>3688 Nanhai Ave</affnadd><x>, </x><affncity>Shenzhen</affncity><x>, </x><affnpost>518060</affnpost><x>, </x><affncountry>PR China</affncountry><x>.</x></affiliation>
</all>'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(data,'xml')

for x in soup.select('affiliation x'):
    x.unwrap()

print(soup)
```

Prints:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<all>
<articletitle>text1<x> </x></articletitle>
<affiliation> <label id="aff1">12</label><affnorg>College of Materials Science and Engineering</affnorg>, <affnorg>Guangdong Research Center for Interfacial Engineering of Functional Materials</affnorg>, <affnorg>Shenzhen University</affnorg>, <affnadd>3688 Nanhai Ave</affnadd>, <affncity>Shenzhen</affncity>, <affnpost>518060</affnpost>, <affncountry>PR China</affncountry>.</affiliation>
<affiliation> <label id="aff2">2</label><affnorg>Key Laboratory of Optoelectronic Devices and Systems of Ministry of Education and Guangdong Province</affnorg>, <affnorg>College of Optoelectronic Engineering</affnorg>, <affnorg>Shenzhen University</affnorg>, <affnadd>3688 Nanhai Ave</affnadd>, <affncity>Shenzhen</affncity>, <affnpost>518060</affnpost>, <affncountry>PR China</affncountry>.</affiliation>
</all>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help I just want it to run on `affiliation` tag only, So how to do that ?

Comment: @YashKumarAtri Updated my answer. You change selector to `"affiliation x"`. More here https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp